# Micro Cat Tracker PCB design

Tags: pcb-design, gps, lora

I would appreciate any advice how to improve PCB design to achieve the highest sensitivity for the GPS signal. The design is based on [S76G chip](http://www.acsip.com.tw/index.php?action=products-detail&fid1=19&fid2=&fid3=&id=41&lang=3). The tracker will be sewn or encapsulated in plastic into cat collar together with two dipole wire antennas (GPS 9.04 cm, LORA 8.20 cm, lambda/2 & lambda/4 - 5%) and fine tuned by NanoVNA.

I am not sure if I should include GND pads for both antennas to signal via shielding (GPS & LORA) and make separate grounds for digital, GPS and LORA signals, connected in one place only. The PCB is 27 x 12 mm four layers: VF signal/GND, VF GND, Power lines, Digital signals/GND. The CPWG is designed to 50 Ohms (189/90/100/4.05 w/space/height [um]/er).

X1 is MEMS LSE 32.768kHz oscillator, X2 TCVCXO 26MHz and U2 is LDO 1.8V

[image: PCB design]

[image: Very first PCB design]

Comment: I’ve not seen a dipole used for GNSS.

Comment: The GPS signal is circularly polarized. While a dipole may still pick up something, I think you should consider a separate, powered GPS antenna positioned away from your main board and LORA radiation. Also, consider using flexible pcb to make antenna instead of bulky wires, for a more comfortable kitty experience.